# hasMany relation problam laravel 5

Tags: laravel, has-many

I am trying to print each page's category next to the page's name.
so I did a model and named it Page. and inside I have this:

```
public function cat() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cat');
}
```

this is my controller:

```
public function pages()
{
    $view = view('cp.pages.all');
    $view->pages = Page::all();
    return $view;
}
```

inside my view I have this:

```
@foreach($pages as $page)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $page->cat->nam }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $cat->id }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

while `name` is the field's name inside my database for the category's name.

but I keep getting this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp\www\mvc\resources\views\cp\pages\all.blade.php)
```

and ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like not every page has a category assigned. You can avoid this error by wrapping it inside an `@if`:

```
<td>
    @if($page->cat)
        {{ $page->cat->nam }}
    @endif
</td>
```

Or in a one liner:

```
<td>{{ ($page->cat ? $page->cat->nam : '') }}</td>
```